# How can I sync .vcf contact  photos between Android 2.2 and Gmail?

Tags: contacts, gmail

I can save all of the contacts to one .vcf file, then use a PC to import it to a Gmail account but there are no photo in the Gmail contacts. I checked the .vcf file there is photo data in it. Is there any function or app can sync the photo from an Android phone to Gmail?

Comment: As per Walialu's comment, you do not need to transfer contacts manually.  Note however that contact pictures on your phone from Facebook will not be transferred to GMail, because Facebook does not allow this.

Answer (score 5):

Settings > Accounts & Sync > john.doe@gmail.com tick the Sync Contacts checkbox :) Make your phone connect to the internet and wait to see the google magic :)

Just in my case it syncs the contact photos perfectly :)